# Python testing true/false condition on data frame column and returning output in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to coding in Python so I'm trying to get to grips with some basics - any input is appreciated.

I have a list of weekly dates, and am trying to run an 'if' statement on the days, i.e. if the day number is less than 7, create a column with a factor x, or else create a factor y - as in the table below:

```
    week        day check       factor
0   2017-01-08  8   False       x
1   2017-01-15  15  False       x
2   2017-01-22  22  False       x
3   2017-01-29  29  False       x
4   2017-02-05  5   True        y
```

I tried the code below:

```
if df['day'] <7 :
    factor=weeks['day']/7
else:
    ....
```

and got an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous
```

which I have looked into, and understand that the code above is attempting to test the whole column and hence there can not be an unambiguous true/false response. I have seen some comments about all/any, but these also do not give me the response I'm looking for. Is there a way of testing each item in a column and returning a different output depending on the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If needed convert the 'week' column `datetime` dtype using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) then you can just compare the day attribute using [`dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) and use this as the condition for [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [47]:
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'])
df['factor'] = np.where(df['week'].dt.day < 7, 'y', 'x')
df

Out[47]:
        week  day  check factor
0 2017-01-08    8  False      x
1 2017-01-15   15  False      x
2 2017-01-22   22  False      x
3 2017-01-29   29  False      x
4 2017-02-05    5   True      y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

This should work for your use case:

```
df['factor'] = df.apply(lambda row: "y" if row['day'] < 7 else "x", axis=1)
```

This will iterate over each row (`axis=1`), and check the `day` value.  If it is less than 7, the value will be 'y', else it will be 'n'.

This outputs (for example):

```
    check  day        week factor
 0  False    8  2017-01-08      x
 1   True    5  2017-02-05      y
```

Also, since you already have a "day" column, you can just work with it directly and avoid an apply:

```
msk = df['day'] < 7   # Series of True/False values based on condition
df[factor] = msk.replace([True, False], ['y', 'x']) #convert True/False to y/x
```

Comment: Although this works, generally one should not recommend the use of `apply` where a vectorised solution exists as it can confuse users